# MYSQL: Incluir datos que no son iguales en ambas tablas

Tags: mysql

Tengo 3 tablas donde la primera es de notas que los usuarios van registrando
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y la otra es de empresas registras
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y la ultima de  usuarios registrados por las empresas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi intención es que la consulta obtenga los datos de las tablas de usuarios (empresa y usuarios) con las id de la primera tabla NOTAS.
Esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT notas.*, 

        empresa_usuarios_data.nombres_us, 
        empresa_usuarios_data.apellidos_us,

        empresa_data.avatar AS avatarEmpresa, 
        empresa_usuarios_data.avatar AS avatarUsuarios

        FROM notas 

        INNER JOIN empresa_usuarios_data ON empresa_usuarios_data.id_user = notas.id_user
        INNER JOIN empresa_data ON empresa_data.id_empresa = empresa_usuarios_data.id_empresa

        WHERE notas.id_empresa = 3
```

Pero el problema como ven es que la columna id_user de la primera tabla Notas, existen registros con el numero 0 que son las empresas, pero este 0 no esta registrado en ninguna de las dos tablas.

y por tal motivo **no me devuelve estos registros con el numero 0**, y quiero obtenerlos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
como podria modificar mi consulta para que me incluya estos registros con el numero 0

Answer (score 0):

No veo en la tabla usuarios un user con id 0, entonces no haria la relación como es el caso de los otros 49,50,51... Prueba agregando un registro con id 0 en los usuarios y haz la consulta nuevamente, puede que lo este haciendo bien pero falte ese usuario registrado en tu BD.

Me cuentas como te fue, saludos.

Comment: el id 0 son las empresas que no tienen id de usuario, por eso les he puesto 0, mi intención es incluir estos registros con el numero 0 ya probé con left join  y sigue igual

Comment: Prueba colocando un `FULL OUTER JOIN` si no te funciona el `LEFT JOIN` Ahora.. Puedes hacerlo así: `SELECT u.ID_USER FROM notas n JOIN empresas e ON e.id_empresa = n.id_empresa JOIN usuarios u ON u.id_empresa = e.id_empresa WHERE n.id_empresa = 3` prueba a ver que tal.